# How can i add a tag and a string in requests.get() to crawl data using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here is my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd

links = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\links.csv',encoding = 'utf-8',dtype=str)

for i in range(1,10):

    link = links.iloc[i,0]
    for count in range(1,5):
        r = requests.get(link + str(count))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
        ##comp links

        for links in soup.find_all('th',{"id":"c_name"}):
            link = links.find('a')
            li = link['href'][3:]
            print("https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/" + li)
```

I am getting the below error :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tag' and 'str'

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your source code. You made a concatenation of an instance of "Tag" class (li) with the string that has an URL.

Try to extract the information that you want from the tag before the concatenation. For example, if you want to get the text in the link use this.

```
print("https://www.hindustanyellowpages.in/Ahmedabad/" + li.text)
```

Comment: but the links i want to scrap are nested under  this concatenation                               
 " r = requests.get(link + str(count)) " ,  there are many links in that  csv file so I cannot do this like  one by one extraction.

Comment: In the line 'r = requests.get(link + str(count))' the 'link' variable is not a Tag instance yet. At that time 'link' must be a string from your csv file, so you should be able to concatenate them at that point.

Comment: so what should i do now to concatenate this tag and string.